Error remove python3.12 - ubuntu 24.04
user@notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
user@notebook:~$ sudo apt remove python3.12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : Depends: python3.12 (>= 3.12.3-0~) but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) but it is not installable or
                        base-files (< 12.3) but 13ubuntu10.1 is to be installed
               Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


Welcome to Askubuntu. May I ask why you are doing this?

This is like removing one of the wheels of your car. Your car won't go anywhere. Similarly Ubuntu won't run without the installed python.

Now you will have to reinstall Ubuntu. Never mess up with system python
